# same numbers but different shape when slicing 2 dimensional arrays in python with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm messing around with 2-dimensional slicing and don't understand why leaving out some defaults  grabs the same values from the original array but produces different output. What's going on with the double brackets and shape changing?

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
y = x[2]
z = x[2:,:]

print y
print z

print shape(y)
print shape(z) 

[6 7 8]
[[6 7 8]]
(3L,)
(1L, 3L)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a two dimensional array, an instance of NumPy's `ndarray` object. You can index/slice these objects in essentially two ways: basic and advanced.

`y[2]` fetches the row at index 2 of the array, returning the array `[6 7 8]`. You're doing **basic** slicing because you've specified only an integer. You can also specify a tuple of slice objects and integers for basic slicing, e.g. `x[:,2]` to select the right-hand column.

With basic slicing, you're also reducing the number of dimensions of the returned object (in this case from two to just one):

> An integer, i, returns the same values as i:i+1 except the dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by 1.

So when you ask for the shape of `y`, this is why you only get back one dimension (from your two-dimensional `x`).

**Advanced** slicing occurs when you specify an `ndarray`: or a tuple with at least one sequence object or `ndarray`. This is the case with `x[2:,:]` since `2:` counts as a sequence object.

You get back an `ndarray`. When you ask for its shape, you will get back all of the dimensions (in this case two):

> The shape of the output (or the needed shape of the object to be used for setting) is the broadcasted shape.

In a nutshell, as soon as you start slicing along any dimension of your array with `:`, you're doing advanced slicing and not basic slicing.

One brief point worth mentioning: basic slicing returns a view onto the original array (changes made to `y` will be reflected in `x`). Advanced slicing returns a brand new copy of the array.

You can read about array indexing and slicing in much more detail [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).